# Issue With Casting Parent Class Object as Child

Tags: c++, casting, bison

I'm currently implementing a compiler for the toy language "Micro" and have created some classes to deal with ASTs.  The parser tool I'm using is Bison.  I'm at the point where I'm trying to generate assembly for while loops and if/else statements, but am having an issue with casting a parent class object ASTNode as one of its children, WhileNode.

In my parser, I've declared my return types for all of these nodes as the parent class ASTNode.

```
%type <node> if_stmt stmt base_stmt loop_stmt read_stmt write_stmt control_stmt return_stmt assign_stmt else_part while_stmt func_decl

%union{
  std::string* s;
  std::list<std::string> * str_list;
  ASTNode * node;
  std::list<ASTNode*> * ast_list;
  JumpType * jtype;
  Conditional * condition;
}
```

In the while_stmt rule, I initialize the WhileNode without the stmt_list it contains.  This is so I can accurately store the currentBlockID, for generating labels, branch statements, etc.

```
while_stmt      : _WHILE _OPAREN cond _CPAREN decl 
                { 
                  currentBlockID = scope_iterator;
                  SymbolTable* tmp = new SymbolTable("BLOCK " + std::to_string(scope_iterator++), ststack.top());
                  ststack.top()->children.push_back(tmp);
                  ststack.push(tmp);
                  $<node>$ = new WhileNode($3->left_expr, $3->right_expr, currentBlockID, $3->jtype, ASTNodeType::WHILE);
                } 
                stmt_list _ENDWHILE  
                {  
                  ststack.pop(); 
                  dynamic_cast<WhileNode *> $<node>6->copyStmtList(*7);
                  $$ = $<node>6;
                }
                ;
```

I've defined the WhileNode in a mid-rule, so that I can trap the currentBlockID before this blockID is iterated in other node constructs (an if/else node will also increment the blockID.)  My issue is with a dynamic_cast in the end of the rule.  I've tried doing this with a static and dynamic cast, but am having issues with both.

Here's the error I'm currently getting with the dynamic cast:

```
src/parser.yy: In function ‘int yyparse()’:
src/parser.yy:388:81: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
                   dynamic_cast<WhileNode *> $<node>6->copyStmtList(*7);
```

I've referenced this question for implementing it in this way, but still was having issues: [How do I cast a parent class as the child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089726/how-do-i-cast-a-parent-class-as-the-child-class).

The reason I'm using the dynamic_cast is because since the return type is an ASTNode, it doesn't have the child's method copyStmtList().  Any help with improving this casting method would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm a fool.  I didn't realize that I accidentally ommited the '$' from '*$7', in which case trying to do anything with *7 is just dereferencing an int type (which is clearly invalid.)  I apologize for the mistake.

Comment: That's not how you write dynamic_cast either; you need parentheses. As it happens, bison will parenthesize the expansion of $6, but you shouldn't rely on that.